# The differences between the "state of affairs" words

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

- 状況
- 様子
- 事情
- 事態
- 情勢
- 形勢
- 動静
- 成り行き
- 雲行き
- 内情
- 内実
- 実情
- 実相
- 向背

What are the differences between each of these words? I know asking the difference between each one of these is a very big request, hence why I asked on this forum. But if someone can help me and answer the differences between all of them then I would greatly appreciate it to the moon, and it would greatly help my learning. I would truly appreciate it a lot if somebody could do so if possible.

Comment: I don't mean this to be rude, but this is what dictionaries are for. I also don't think you are going to get a better answer here than what you'll find on a dictionary.